# What is difference between contains with includes method in immutable js

Tags: immutable.js

What is difference between *contains* and *includes* methods in immutable js?

The [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/includes) just says

> ALIAS
>   contains()

Comment: Improve grammar. Quote the documentation and add a meaningful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already said it: *includes* is an alias for *contains*, meaning: It's the same function. You can see that by looking into the actual source code, [dist/immutable.js, line 4824](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/dist/immutable.js#L4824):

```
CollectionPrototype.contains = CollectionPrototype.includes;
```